# Notepad++ hangs every time I switch back to a very large file

Tags: notepad++

I have a 65Mb file and when I tell NotePad++ to view it as a language (so I can collapse things) it takes about 30s during which the application is totally unresponsive. After this the file can be navigated smoothly.

This would be fine, except every time I switch to another file, and back to this tab, it locks up for another 30s. I assume it is optimising memory or something but it makes toggling between multiple files a huge problem.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try another Text Editor eg VSCode or Sublime Text 2 and tell feedback about working with large file. I don't have problem with VSCode & too many large files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and the only way that solved it is to switch to a portable version. The one from portableapps works fine for me.

Comment: Hello, this isn't really a solution to the problem, it doesn't explain why opening large files is slow with the installed one, neither does it help if they want to keep that version.